# Find a file in a tree in python-3.4 on windows

Tags: python, python-3.4

I want to search a file in a tree.

I know the filename and the root of the tree, but I want to find the file path. I use python-3.4 on windows 7.

I have:

```
#I have a list with C header file name => my_headers_list that look like:
for part in my_headers_list:
    print(part)

#show this
common.h
extern.h
something.h
else.h
```

I also have a tree ( something/ is a folder):

```
Software/
    something.c
    Component1/
        extern.c
        extern.h
    Component2/
        Core/
            common.h
            common.c
        Config/
            common_m.c
            common_m.h
    Component3/
        Managment/
        Core/
        Config/
```

etc it's an example but it's really close of my real case.

I want:

```
#a list like the first one, but with the full path of the files
for part in my_headers_list:
    print(part)

#show this
Software/Component2/Core/common.h
Software/Component1/extern.h
Software/Component3/Core/something.h
Software/Component3/Management/else.h
```

I precise that it should be generic, so I can't make hard link or hard path etc.

For the moment I've try some tricky scripts with some os.listdir etc but it seems messy and don't always work.

```
#I try something like this
dirs = os.listdir("Software/")
for part in dirs:
    #don't know how to correctly manage these informations to get what I want.
```

Do you guys have some way to do this ?

Keep in mind that I don't want to add any lib or plugin to my python.

Thank you,

Regards,

Comment: [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk)

Comment: or [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html)

Comment: If you are using 3.4 you also have [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) if you prefer the OO style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question resolved in comments.

I'll use [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) / [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html).

Thank to @kevin @Lafexlos